# Including libraries in G++ using -l confusion

Tags: c++, g++

I'm trying to use an external library but I'm confused how it all fits together.

I have the following code that all I'm trying to do is get compiled:

```
#include "cryptopp/sha.h"

int main()
{
    CryptoPP::SHA1 sha1;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using g++ to do the compiling, and from my research I've gathered that I need to append

```
-lcryptopp
```

to the end of the compile command like so:

```
g++ crypto.cpp -o crypto.exe -lcryptopp
```

but I get the following error:

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcryptopp

This is where I get confused, I'm not really sure what the -lcryptopp is looking for, is it looking for the sha.cpp/sha.h files that I'm including in my code? But more importantly how do I specify that whatever it's looking for I just want it to look in the cryptopp folder in the same folder as my main .cpp?

Comment: Somewhere you will have installed a file called `libcryptopp.a`. If it is at `<path>`, add `-L <path>` to your command line.

Comment: The -L option will tell the compiler [at least if it's gcc or similar] where to find the library files. So `-Lsomedir` is what you need - where `somedir` is the location of your cryptopp library.

Comment: There's also the `-L` option to specify the path, where the library files should be looked up from the linker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-lcryptopp` tells linker to link your exe against the dynamic library (shared object) file `libcryptopp.so`. GNU linker searches for shared object files in various directories like `/lib`, `/usr/lib` and others.

You can specify additional directories to search for library files with `-L` option, like `-L/usr/local/lib`. You should find out where is your library file `libcryptopp.so` located and pass the path to it with `-L` option.

Comment: When I downloaded the crypopp files shouldn't libcryptopp.so have come with it?

Comment: @user1157885 If you have downloaded source files, then certainly not. Typically source files are build and installed with commands `./configure && make && make install`.